# Is there a way to get and parse the response from a redirection request?

Tags: javascript, http

Say I send a request to www.a.com and it returns 302 and redirect to location www.a.com/net/test.do，since it is an API, I would like to parse the response from this request, any way to do this?

Comment: aha. Any chance you're trying to do OAuth 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you can't do (in the browser) is get the 302 response. The second one is the only one you'd get. That behaviour is on purpose, as stated in the [Fetch API spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling):

> Redirects (a response whose status or internal response’s (if any) status is a redirect status) are not exposed to APIs. Exposing redirects might leak information not otherwise available through a cross-site scripting attack.

In node.js, you can stop following redirects whenever you like.

Comment: the example says `A fetch to https://example.org/auth that includes a Cookie marked HttpOnly could result in a redirect to https://other-origin.invalid/4af955781ea1c84a3b11. This new URL contains a secret. If we expose redirects that secret would be available through a cross-site scripting attack.`  I totally got lost by "If we expose redirects" , what does it mean? this redirect url is actually exposed, we can see this redirect url from the response header, can't we??

Comment: But JavaScript code in the browser cannot see that response at all. It will only see the last response in the chain, after all redirects have been followed. The browser will see the 302 response and follow its Location header without ever letting JavaScript know about it.